# How do I add constraints to a programmatically created UIButton placed in a UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, constraints, uistackview

I have a simple vertical `UIStackView` and in the 3rd subview, I want to place my programmatically created `UIButton`. I can do this but the button is expanding to the full width and height of the subview instead of being the size I'm setting it to in my code. I've created the `UIStackView` using the storyboard but I'm adding this button programmatically so I have better control over the look of the button.

```
  let doThisButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 40))
  doThisButton.setTitle("Let's do this.", forState: .Normal)
  doThisButton.setTitleShadowColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
  doThisButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  doThisButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3
  doThisButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "b7b7b7").CGColor
  doThisButton.layer.borderWidth = 0

  liftLogStackView.addArrangedSubview(doThisButton)
```

In Apple's documentation, I found `UILayoutGuide` which seemed like it might work but now I don't think so. I tried this:

```
  let container = UILayoutGuide()
  doThisButton.addLayoutGuide(container)

  doThisButton.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(container.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).active = true
  doThisButton.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(container.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0).active = true

  liftLogStackView.addArrangedSubview(doThisButton)
  container.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor).active = true
```

and it made no difference.

A lot of SO searching didn't turn up any answers specific to my problem, so I'm hoping someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would be to pack this `UIButton` into a `UIView`. Then the `UIView` will stretch out and take all place needed. The `UIButton` will stay the size you have defined. Now you are able to define the constraints depending on the container view.

I have made a short Playground example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TestViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Test"

        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown

        let stackview = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480))
        stackview.axis = .vertical
        stackview.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually

        let text = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 20))
        text.text = "Hello, i am a label"
        text.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 100))
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        containerView.addSubview(text)

        stackview.addArrangedSubview(containerView)

        let text2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
        text2.text = "Hello, i am another label"
        text2.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        stackview.addArrangedSubview(text2)

        self.view.addSubview(stackview)
    }
}

let testController = TestViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = testController.view
testController
```

[image: Storyboard Example]

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Prine. I'm having one more issue with this thing so if you have a chance to take a look at this new question I just posted ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393659/why-is-uiimageview-content-mode-ignore)), I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the alignment of the `UIStackView`. By default it is set so subviews will fill the dimension perpendicular to the axis. In your case, the width.

```
liftLogStackView.alignment = .center
```

That will apply to all subview in the `UIStackView` which may not be what you want. In that case, just add the button as a subview in another `UIView` then add that view to the `UIStackView`. Your new view will then be full width but you can constrain the button to whatever size you want.

Also, I'd suggest reading the [`UIStackView` Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview). There is a lot of useful information in there about how to setup your layouts.