# Why is UIImageView.content mode ignored

Tags: swift, uistackview, contentmode

I have a vertical `UIStackView` with three subviews and I want to center the content in all three of these subviews. I'm doing this all programmatically, not with the storyboard. I started by trying to use the storyboard and only adding the last `arrangedSubview` but that complicated things more.

I've tried setting the '.contentMode` on the stack view itself, on each of the subviews, and all of them at the same time (as seen below). None of them have any affect - everything in these three subviews remains flush left against their container views no matter what I do. I also made sure Auto Resize Subviews was not checked in IB based on something I saw in another thread but it didn't make a difference either.

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let horizontalCenter = self.view.frame.width/2
    let verticalCenter = self.view.frame.height/2

    // the stackview that lives in 'emptyLogView'
    let liftLogStackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: horizontalCenter, y: verticalCenter, width: 320, height: 480))
    liftLogStackView.axis = .Vertical
    liftLogStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.FillEqually
    liftLogStackView.contentMode = .Center

    // 1st subview
    let weightsImage = UIImage(named: "weights_image")
    let weightsContainerView = UIImageView(image: weightsImage)
    weightsContainerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 77)
    weightsContainerView.contentMode = .Center

    // 2nd subview
    let noLiftsMessageContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 40))
    let noLiftsMessage = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 20))
    noLiftsMessage.text = "You don't have any lifts saved."
    noLiftsMessage.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "b7b7b7")
    noLiftsMessageContainerView.contentMode = .Center

    // 3rd subview
    let letsDoThisContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 40))
    let doThisButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 36))
    doThisButton.setTitle("Let's do this.", forState: .Normal)
    doThisButton.setTitleShadowColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
    doThisButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    doThisButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "b7b7b7").CGColor
    doThisButton.layer.borderWidth = 0
    letsDoThisContainerView.contentMode = .Center

    noLiftsMessageContainerView.addSubview(noLiftsMessage)
    letsDoThisContainerView.addSubview(doThisButton)

    liftLogStackView.addArrangedSubview(weightsContainerView)

    liftLogStackView.addArrangedSubview(noLiftsMessageContainerView)

    liftLogStackView.addArrangedSubview(letsDoThisContainerView)

    liftLogStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    emptyLogView.addSubview(liftLogStackView)

    let horizontalCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: liftLogStackView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: emptyLogView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let verticalCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: liftLogStackView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: emptyLogView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    emptyLogView.addConstraint(horizontalCenterConstraint)
    emptyLogView.addConstraint(verticalCenterConstraint)
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found one more thing on a 6-yr old SO thread to try but it didn't work either:

```
    let letsDoThisContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 40))
    let doThisButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 36))
    doThisButton.setTitle("Let's do this.", forState: .Normal)
    doThisButton.setTitleShadowColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
    doThisButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    doThisButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "b7b7b7").CGColor
    doThisButton.layer.borderWidth = 0

    // this is the new thing
    let contentAlignmentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    liftLogStackView.contentMode = contentAlignmentMode
```

I also tried different setting the `contentMode` to `.Right` and nothing happen. The elements are all stuck flush left no matter what I do.

**UPDATE 2**

I found part of the answer (I think). It looks like `UIStackViewAlignment` is what I need. So I now have this:

```
    let liftLogStackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: horizontalCenter, y: verticalCenter, width: 320, height: 480))
    liftLogStackView.axis = .Vertical
    liftLogStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.FillEqually

    // Finally, this has an affect on the alignment
    liftLogStackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center
```

But instead of being centered, it looks like it's almost right aligned (the blue box is the stack view):

[image]

It looks to me like the views don't know the bounds of the parent views they're in but I think I'm creating the stack view and its subviews correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried calling `liftLogStackView.setNeedsLayout()` after fully configuring it?

Comment: I hadn't tried that but I just did and unfortunately it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

> but I think I'm creating the stack view and its subviews correctly

Think again. You are creating them completely wrong. Let's consider just this one arranged view:

```
let weightsImage = UIImage(named: "weights_image")
let weightsContainerView = UIImageView(image: weightsImage)
weightsContainerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 77)
```

You are doing *two* things wrong here (maybe three, depending how you count).

- You must not set any frames. That is meaningless. This is a stack view! It does its work through constraints. Constraints are the opposite of frames; you use one or the other.
- You must set constraints! You have not given the image view any constraints. So it will will simply want to set itself to the size of the view. In particular, all the work that the stack view will do is based on the `intrinsicContentSize` of its arranged views. You need to provide enough information to make that work the way you intend.
- You have forgotten to set the image view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`. Thus, the constraints that will be imposed by the stack view will *conflict* with the image view's autoresizing. In fact, I am pretty sure that if you just look in the console when you run your project, you will *see* that the runtime is screaming "Conflict!" at you.

> I'm doing this all programmatically, not with the storyboard

That is a noble goal, but I would suggest that you'd be better off doing it in the storyboard (or a xib file), because it will do a better job of all this than your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. That's very helpful and after making the changes, it works. I actually did have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` but somehow left it out in my post. I took your advice and went back to the storyboard approach. But I still want the button to be customized so would I create the stack view on the storyboard with just two subviews then programmatically add the third subview with my custom button in it?

Comment: Everything you do in your code to your button can be configured in the storyboard instead. (Of course, we now have a credibility issue: I no longer believe the code you are showing is your code.)

Comment: Are you kidding me right now? Why would you say something like that? It absolutely is my code.

Comment: "I actually did have translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false but somehow left it out in my post". That would be a lot of leaving out, since you would need it for every one of your views.

Comment: I'm trying to learn here, Matt. While researching a similar problem I had with one view last week, I saw an example that used this line. So I used it and it worked. Now I had this similar issue and I put it in one spot only. Why? Because I didn't know I need it for each view (until now). But the whole thing wasn't working so how would I have concluded that with 2 or 3 other things I was doing wrong? I've also been trying many different things, commenting/uncommenting code, moving stuff around, etc. Missing stuff happens. Are you here to help people or make snarky accusations?

Comment: I have many purposes! One of them is to tell you that the way to ask a question on SO is to show your _real_ code. Another is to help you, and the way I'm now doing that is to tell you that if the code you showed _is_ your real code, then everything you are doing to that button _could_ be done in the storyboard if you so desired.

Comment: I'm well aware without your help that we need to show our _real_ code in our questions and that's exactly what I do. Let me help you in return with some advice. Your help would be much more appreciated if you didn't deliver it with an arrogant undertone (which I ignored the first time) and accusations.

Comment: "I'm well aware without your help that we need to show our real code in our questions and that's exactly what I do" I understood you to say that you had not done so.